# How to find cause of Warning: PropTypes has been moved to a separate package

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If I get the warning "Warning: PropTypes has been moved to a separate package." How can I locate which npm package is still using it? The warning doesnt offer any details about what file or package is causing it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React deprecated the usage of `propTypes` from their main package so you can't use `React.PropTypes`. When you use `React.PropTypes` it gives you a warning but when you use `propTypes` from `prop-types` package you are good.

That's It :)

You can use this knowledge to find the list of npm packages which are using it through the following command.

```
find ./node_modules -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'PropTypes' | cut -d/ -f3 | sort | uniq | xargs -I{} grep -L 'prop-types' ./node_modules/{}/package.json
```

The above command will find all the npm packages having `PropTypes` word present in any of their files, then it looks into the `package.json` file of that package to check whether the `prop-types` package is included or not. If `prop-types` package is missing then it prints the path of that package.

PS: I'm no bash expert so I've taken little help from [this](https://serverfault.com/a/291327/402567) serverfault answer. (To find the unique npm packages containing the `PropTypes` word)

[image]

*PPS: The answer assumes that you are using a Unix machine.*

Comment: So this is a list of packages where prop-types are missing? and they all create that warning?

Comment: Ummm...Yeah that's the idea. If package.json doesn't contain `prop-types` dependency but PropTypes is used in any of the files then it assumes that the package is using the deprecated propTypes from the main React package. Again, This might not be 110% accurate but it's very helpful.

Comment: That's awesome idea! How to update such dependencies as eslint-plugin-react after that? I also got in my list

Comment: You mean `eslint-plugin-react` is also in the list of plugins which are using propTypes from react package? In this case, You can try upgrading to the latest stable version and see if the maintainer has addressed the warning by using prop-types package.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea so might not be that useful or there would be a better solution but you can use `npm ls` command to get the dependency tree. Then you can locate the packages that depends on react but not prop-types. This is sort of a manual solution and might be a better one.

More info about `npm ls` [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> npm ls [[<@scope>/]<pkg> ...]
>
> aliases: list, la, ll
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> This command will print to stdout all the versions of packages that
>   are installed, as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure.